# Creating UILabels according to the number of array elements in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

This is my first question here, so i apologize for any bad.

I have an array of Strings which includes logs to be displayed. I want to display each of these logs in separate UILabel elements where they have equal widths and different heights according to the number of lines each log has. Following screen is actually like what I want to trying to do (do not care the tab bar, what I am looking for is UILabel elements each having logs):

http://i.hizliresim.com/q20G6W.png

I am using XCode 6 with iOS SDK 8.0 and I may be counted as beginner in Swift and actually I have problems creating a view element programmatically and setting layout constraints for them. So your answers will possibly guide me. My question is:

**How can I create and put in view any number of UILabel elements and set layout constraints for them (both programmatically) to display those logs/messages/strings etc. similar to the image above?**

Comment: What you should really be looking at is creating a `UITableView` with variable height elements.  The key is overriding the `UITableViewDataSource` method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: By using `UITableView` you get a great deal of free functionality including scrolling, layout, view management, etc.

Comment: To be honest, I have already solved this problem using UITableView. However, I want to learn how to achieve this using UILabels to have a new point of view. Thanks for quick reply anyway

Comment: And what is, when you have more labels than your screen is height? So you need a ScrollView. A TableView already implements a ScrollView, a Cell and (if Basic Layout) a Label. So all what you need. If you really want to make it complicated, create Labels programmtically and use AutoLayout to automatically calculated the needed space.